# Building a dataset using Gab.com API using Python generating KeyError 0

Tags: python, api

I am trying to build a dataset from Gab.com using its API. I have 20 seed accounts and would like to get all of their followers and accounts they follow up to the third or fourth level. I am using a simple [gab library](https://github.com/isd1ff/gab-lib) for the API because I could not find helpful documentation.

I am getting this error only on the second level followers. Also, it seems like it is only returning the first 40 followers of each seed account, not all the followers. Is this a limitation from their API so Gab doesn't go down or do I need to paginate?

```
488
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-4-59b9ed5a855b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/Desktop/gab/api/main.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Desktop/gab/api')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/gab/api/main.py", line 62, in <module>
    accounts2.append(followers_data[i]["id"])

KeyError: 0
```

This is my code: (seed user handles are removed)

```
from gab import lib

import json


BASE_URL="https://api.gab.com/"
CLIENT_TOKEN = "???????????????????????????????"

auth = lib.AuthAPI(BASE_URL,CLIENT_TOKEN)
gab = lib.GabAPI(auth)



seeds = [ "string1", "string2", ...]

accounts = []

accounts1 = []

accounts2 = []

for seed in seeds:
    seed_data = gab.user_search(seed)
    accounts.append(seed_data[0]["id"])
    
for account in accounts:
    followers_data = gab.user_followers(account).json()
    for i in range (0,len(followers_data)):
        accounts1.append(followers_data[i]["id"])
        
accounts1 = set(accounts1)

print (len(accounts1))

for account in accounts1:
    followers_data = gab.user_followers(account).json()
    for i in range (0,len(followers_data)):
        accounts2.append(followers_data[i]["id"])
        
accounts2 = set(accounts2)

print (len(accounts2))
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you got a result back that was None, but Python was expecting SOMETHING.
(you're getting a KeyError, so it's like you're asking for a value that doesn't exist)

try (pun intended) something like..

```
    try:
        for account in accounts1:
            followers_data = gab.user_followers(account).json()
            for i in range (0,len(followers_data)):
                accounts2.append(followers_data[i]["id"])
    except:
        pass
```

but in the day, Visual Basic had a thing called "On Error Resume Next"
basically meaning "if something bad happens... just ignore it and keep working on the next thing."

That's essentially what is happening above.
You *should* add an error value in there  "except KeyError" or whatever your error coming up in the debug is

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to use try/except without specifying specific exceptions. You should also aim to have your try block cover the smallest amount of code possible. Otherwise, it's far too easy for easily correctible errors to get missed because they just get swallowed up.